# scala type of forms

Tags: scala, gatling

i'm new to scala language . what i wanted to know is i need to select a value from a drop down.what happens here is drop down as below.

```
<input id="categoryDid" class=" x-form-text x-form-field print_underline x-form-empty-field x-trigger-noedit" type="text" name="category" autocomplete="off" size="24" tabindex="1" readonly="" style="width: 132px;">    drop down data some where else.    <div id="ext-gen274" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 148px; margin-bottom: 8px; height: 63px;">
```

drop down data some where else as below.

```
    <div id="ext-gen274" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 148px; margin-bottom: 8px; height: 63px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item">--Select--</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Mobile Phone</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Tablet</div>
</div>
```

i'm using gatling / scala combination .now what i need to select is "Mobile Phone". i used `formParam("categoryDid", "Mobile Phone")` but seems this is not working.
can some one help ?

Answer (score 0):

The NAME of your parameter (see input field) is category, not categoryDid:

```
formParam("category", "Mobile Phone")
```